# pywinauto - find/read text in a dialog/popup that is not part of any control of the dialog

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I am trying to read the text "This return is due on or before" from below dialog/popup of an application that I am trying to do some automation on using pywinauto, I am able to automate other controls on this pop-up, i.e. OK/Close/etc., just not able to get to the "text" and i have tried below code, but it seems this text is not part of any control of the dialog, so is there any other way i can get to the text?
[Dialog/popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vidt0.jpg)

Inspect.exe shows this for the popup [inspect_exe_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtXbn.jpg)

I have tried below code so far:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="win32").start("app.exe")
#This is the dialog with the text i am after
dialog=app.RTI
dialog.window_text()
dialog.texts()
dialog.print_control_identifiers()
dialog.children()
dialog.descendants()
for child in dialog.descendants():
 print (child.window_text())
 print (child.texts())
```

output:

```
>>> dialog.window_text()
'RTI'
>>> dialog.texts()
['RTI']
>>> dialog.print_control_identifiers()
Control Identifiers:

Tdlg_askbox - 'RTI'    (L711, T344, R1208, B482)
['Tdlg_askbox', 'RTI', 'RTITdlg_askbox']
child_window(title="RTI", class_name="Tdlg_askbox")
   |
   | ComboBox - ''    (L723, T503, R1196, B535)
   | ['RTIComboBox', 'ComboBox']
   | child_window(class_name="TComboBox")
   |
   | Edit - ''    (L723, T465, R1196, B497)
   | ['Edit', 'RTIEdit']
   | child_window(class_name="TEdit")
   |
   | CheckBox - 'Don't ask me this again'    (L723, T641, R1196, B667)
   | ['CheckBox', "Don't ask me this againCheckBox", "Don't ask me this again"]
   | child_window(title="Don't ask me this again", class_name="TCheckBox")
   |
   | Button - 'Help'    (L843, T432, R956, B470)
   | ['Help', 'HelpButton', 'Button', 'Button0', 'Button1']
   | child_window(title="Help", class_name="TButton")
   |
   | Button - 'Cancel'    (L723, T596, R836, B634)
   | ['Cancel', 'CancelButton', 'Button2']
   | child_window(title="Cancel", class_name="TButton")
   |
   | Button - 'OK'    (L963, T432, R1076, B470)
   | ['OK', 'Button3', 'OKButton']
   | child_window(title="OK", class_name="TButton")
   |
   | Button - '&No'    (L963, T551, R1076, B589)
   | ['&NoButton', 'Button4', '&No']
   | child_window(title="&No", class_name="TButton")
   |
   | Button - '&Yes'    (L843, T551, R956, B589)
   | ['&Yes', '&YesButton', 'Button5']
   | child_window(title="&Yes", class_name="TButton")
>>> dialog.children()
[<win32_controls.ComboBoxWrapper - '', ComboBox, 265638>, <win32_controls.EditWrapper - '', Edit, 265636>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - 'Don't ask me this again', CheckBox, 265634>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - 'Help', Button, 265632>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - 'Cancel', Button, 265630>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - 'OK', Button, 265628>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - '&No', Button, 265626>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - '&Yes', Button, 265624>]
>>> dialog.descendants()
[<win32_controls.ComboBoxWrapper - '', ComboBox, 265638>, <win32_controls.EditWrapper - '', Edit, 265636>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - 'Don't ask me this again', CheckBox, 265634>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - 'Help', Button, 265632>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - 'Cancel', Button, 265630>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - 'OK', Button, 265628>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - '&No', Button, 265626>, <win32_controls.ButtonWrapper - '&Yes', Button, 265624>]
>>> for child in dialog.descendants():
...  print (child.window_text())
...  print (child.texts())
...

['']

['', '']
Don't ask me this again
["Don't ask me this again"]
Help
['Help']
Cancel
['Cancel']
OK
['OK']
&No
['&No']
&Yes
['&Yes']
```

Comment: `app.windows()` returns all top level dialogs/popups. Sometimes context menu or popup could be in another process (check it in `Inspect.exe` tool from Windows SDK). In this case you need `Desktop(backend="uia").windows()` to list all top windows/elements.

Comment: I am able to get hold of the popup, i am just not able to get to the text. As per your suggestion, I have used `inspect.exe` and changed `backend="win32"`, now i see more control info, but i am still not able to workout how to get to the desired text message. From listing down print_control_identifiers() , there is a ComboBox control. Is that the control that might hold the text i am after?

Comment: added image of the inspect.exe data for popup window, and updated code output for `backend="win32"`

Comment: Sorry for delay. The output of `.print_control_identifiers()` doesn't map on the popup window screenshot. That's why I asked about `app.windows()` returned list. There should at least 2 top level windows especially for "win32" backend (hierarchy is different for another backend!). So you may need to change the line `dialog = app.RTI`. Maybe you've already figured it out. Please let me know if the issue is still relevant.

Comment: The text message on the screenshot is a static text control in "win32" backend or "Text" control type in "uia" backend.